# Playwright webserver dynamic port configuration

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules, playwright

My playwright tests fail sometimes in the pipeline because ports are already in use so i decided to implement dynamic port assignment for the playwright webserver.

`playwright.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';
import { getPort } from 'get-port-please';
const webserverPort = getPort({ random: true }).then((port) => port);
const webserverUrl = `http://localhost:${webserverPort}`;

export default defineConfig({
    timeout: 100000,
    testDir: 'tests',
  
    fullyParallel: false,
   
    forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
    retries: 0,
    workers: 1,
    reporter: [
    ],

    use: {
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        video: 'on-first-retry',
        baseURL: webserverUrl
        locale: 'en',
    },


    projects: [
        {
            name: 'chromium',
            use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
        },
    ],

    webServer: {
        command: `npm run start -- --port ${webserverPort}`,
        url: webserverUrl,
        reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
    },
});
```

Problem: Playwright tests start/playwright config is used before the port is resolved(getPort command returns promise. When i try to execute the tests playwright claims that port is `Nan` (not resolved). I tried to await but top level await is somehow not allowed in this context. How can i ensure everything resolves before exporting the config?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to export a promise that resolves to the config.

```
const loadConfig = async () => {
  const webserverPort = await getPort({ random: true });
  const webserverUrl = `http://localhost:${webserverPort}`;

  return defineConfig({...})
}

export default loadConfig()
```

Comment: I attempted the suggested approach, but it appears that playwright in this case  cannot utilize anything asynchronous or promise-related because it starts the web server before resolving the promise. I think Playwright expects an already resolved configuration. Due to this behavior, I opted to generate a random high port number as the probability of encountering already chosen ports is negligible